# get extension of file(edit)

Tags: c#, asp.net, response

i want get extension file of url .

for example get extension http://www.iranfairco.com/download-file/02912bb889cb24.
if extension this file is gif.

**EDIT:**

for example this url ["http://www.online-convert.com/result/d8b423c3cbc05000cc52ce7015873e72"](http://www.online-convert.com/result/d8b423c3cbc05000cc52ce7015873e72)

Please help me how can get extension of this url?

Comment: I see nothing here indicating a gif. The url doesn't contain `.gif` and the http request returns a 404.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why does [Path.GetExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension.aspx) not work for you?

**EDIT**
Ah, so your url doesn't specify the extension you are after. That means *anything* could be behind it.

Just by inspecting the string value of the url, you can't see what will behind it. Your (second) example point (ultimately) to a .gif file, but it could also have been a .jpg, .doc (or even .exe).

You will need to do a webrequest to see what you get back. Usually you could try a HEAD to get just the headers (and inspect the content type), but I don't think that will work here. Try Fiddler to see what you get back, then you can refine your question.

Comment: ah yes that would work, but it would not for the example given... I thought you had found a super-awesome function then, I was waiting to be very impressed :D

Comment: this url "http://www.online-convert.com/result/d8b423c3cbc05000cc52ce7015873e72" does not contain .gif

Answer (score 6):

Check out here:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Network/GetHTTPResponseheaders.htm

You will be interested in the response.ContentType which should give you something like "image/gif" for a gif image

Comment: That depends on the content header being set. Given the asp.net tag, I'd imagine @Curt 's answer is the more correct, and that what is required is actually applying a content type in asp.

Comment: @Overflow, I know it requires that the content type needs to be set by the server when it handles that URL call. And my assumption is that this URL is used to provide a file download (as suggested in the URL itself), and most likely the server will return a response stream containing just the image and thus having set a content type. OF course, the content type could be wrong and that depends on the implementation. But to do it correctly, the implementation should provide the correct content type, and thus my answer would be able to find out the file type

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
string path = @"http://www.iranfairco.com/download-file/02912bb889cb24.gif";
 string e = Path.GetExtension(path );
```

Comment: url equal 29493903 does not equal 290930232.gif

Answer (score 1):

This URL appears to perhaps be linking to a page which will have a download for a file.

The `02912bb889cb24` is perhaps a database reference to that file.

Therefore without access to any API for this system, I don't think its possible at all to work out the file extension for the file accessed via this URL

Comment: I tend to see this as being the most accurate answer, with a couple of additions, 1. When the file is uploaded you should be able to get the content-type and save it to the database with the file. Then when the file is downloaded, you should be able to set the content type again.

Answer (score 0):

You can just split the string on char '.' and get the last string in the returned array..

Comment: not if the string does not have the file extension in it... which the example does not

Comment: No obviously because the example is a fail... how is that my fault?

Comment: @Rob, why is the example a fail... it is a perfectly valid URL format